# Passing RUN output to ENV and ARG - Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am learning how to use ARG and ENV in Dockerfiles. in my structure i have local env's in container, this envs will be used an arg to run specific commands, for each env send output to name env file after pass env output to arg (this process must be in Dockerfile), how i can do this?

```
RUN env | grep pentaho_link_bin >> pentaho_link_bin_out && \
    env | grep pentaho_pdi_file >> pentaho_pdi_file_out && \
    env | grep pentaho_folder && >> pentaho_folder_out && \ 
    env | grep pentaho_repository_pass >> pentaho_repository_pass_out

RUN PENTAHO_LINK_BIN_OUT=$(cat pentaho_link_bin_out) && \
    PENTAHO_PDI_FILE_OUT=$(cat pentaho_pdi_file_out) && \
    PENTAHO_FOLDER_OUT=$(cat pentaho_folder_out) && \
    PENTAHO_REPOSITORY_PASS_OUT=$(cat pentaho_repository_pass_out)

ARG PENTAHO_LINK_BIN=${PENTAHO_LINK_BIN_OUT}
ARG PENTAHO_PDI_FILE=${PENTAHO_PDI_FILE_OUT}
ARG PENTAHO_FOLDER=${PENTAHO_FOLDER_OUT}
ARG PENTAHO_REPOSITORY_PASS=${PENTAHO_REPOSITORY_PASS_OUT}

RUN wget ${PENTAHO_LINK_BIN} -O ${PENTAHO_PDI_FILE}
```

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do there.

Comment: A variable you set inside a `RUN` statement isn't going to be visible to other `RUN` statements and it won't be available for use in an `ARG` statement. Build arguments are for passing from *outside* the build environment into the build process (as arguments to the `---build-arg` option of `docker build`).

Comment: @larsks i reached the desired resolution, thank you!